# developing Radio ios App

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a problem when I test my radio iOS app on real device its working well but when the screen or the device is turned off, the radio is stopped and turn off why this happen?
and how to make activity indicator view stopped moving and hide it when the radio is open and finish loading???

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(uodatetimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:   
                                       [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://46.43.64.50:8008/AJYAL.m3u"]];
    player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    player.view.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];
   // player.useApplicationAudioSession=NO;
    spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

    spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 20.0);

    spinner.center=self.view.center;

    [spinner startAnimating];

    [self.view addSubview:spinner];

    MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:
                                 CGRectMake(0, 0, 105, 15)] autorelease];
    volumeView.center = CGPointMake(152,372);
    [volumeView setShowsVolumeSlider:YES];
    [volumeView setShowsRouteButton:YES];
    [volumeView sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:volumeView];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 2 things to enable audio playback in the background:

- Add the "Required background modes" key to your Info.plist file with the "App plays audio" value.
- Set the audio session category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback and activate the audio session:

  `AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

  [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

  [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

To be able to have it playing in background you need to enable in project .plist file `UIBackgroundModes` or Required Background Modes in human readable format and in array for first string row write audio. That will make your app running after the screen is off and while in background.

Comment: Thank you amar i add Required Background Modes in new row as array and i put in item0 string App plays audio because there is no audio just and this not working when i test it on real device

Answer (score 0):

in the `yourProject-pList` add this row

[image: UIBackgroundModes]